How do I map type NpgsqlRange<DateTime> to "tsrange" instead of "tstzrange" (default) in EF Core?
Question: How do I configure Npgsql/EF to map NpgsqlRange<DateTime> to tsrange?
I have a UDF that accepts a single argument of type tsrange:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.my_test(value tsrange)
RETURNS TABLE ("column_a" tsrange) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

My OnModelCreating method of DbContext configures the UDF call as follows:
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyTest(default))
    .HasSchema("data")
    .HasName("my_test")
    .HasParameter("value", parameter => { parameter.Metadata.StoreType = @"tsrange"; });

The issue is that when I call the function I get the following error:
  MessageText: function data.my_test(tstzrange) does not exist

If I change my my_test function to accepts tstzrange argument, then code works as expected.
I can not figure out how to configure Npgsql/EF to map NpgsqlRange<DateTime> to be tsrange rather than default tstzrange.
What I tried:

configuring global type mapping:

NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapComposite(typeof(NpgsqlRange<DateTime>), "tsrange");


configuring type mapping using dataSourceBilder:

dataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<NpgsqlRange<DateTime>>("tsrange");


passing range as UTC, and as Unspecified kinds.

It seems that to make this work I need to provide a type configuration in the runtime model:
ITypeMappingConfiguration? IModel.FindTypeMappingConfiguration(Type propertyType)
    => _typeConfigurations.Count == 0
        ? null
        : _typeConfigurations.GetValueOrDefault(propertyType);

but I can't figure out how to do this.
Here is how I call my UDF:
await using var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
var result = await dbContext.MyTest(new NpgsqlRange<DateTime>(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10)))
    .ToListAsync();

